# Unable to compile server node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi: I am getting the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const char [15], void (&)(beginner_tutorials::stringEditor::Request&, beginner_tutorials::stringEditor::Response&))’
   ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("editBaseString", editor);
```

This is my stringEditorServer.cpp file:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "beginner_tutorials/stringEditor.h"

 void editor(beginner_tutorials::stringEditor::Request  &req,
     beginner_tutorials::stringEditor::Response &res)
{
  res.output = "count to 100 ";
  ROS_INFO("sending back response");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "stringEditorServer");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("editBaseString", editor);
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

This is my stringEditor.srv file:

```
string input
---
string output
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275258/unable-to-compile-server-node/) by [inani47](https://answers.ros.org/users/32531/inani47/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your callback has to return a bool.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inani47](https://answers.ros.org/users/32531/inani47/) on 2017-11-07**:
Thank you good, Sir. You are a life saver.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-11-07**:
If that worked, please mark the question as answered (checkmark at this question)